# Can not refer to RESULTS in org-babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I need to plot data evaluated in org-mode. Referring to `#+RESULTS:` returns
**org-babel-ref-resolve: Reference ‘myResult’ not found in this buffer**
whereas referring to `#+tblname:` works.

```
    #+RESULTS: myResult
    | 2057-01-01 | 10 |
    | 2057-01-02 |  5 |
    | 2057-01-03 |  3 |
    | 2057-01-04 |  2 |

    #+name: myTable
    | 2057-01-01 | 10 |
    | 2057-01-02 |  5 |
    | 2057-01-03 |  3 |
    | 2057-01-04 |  2 |
```

Note the *failing* reference `data=myResult`, while `data=myTable` works.

```
    #+begin_src gnuplot :var data=myTable :exports code :file basic-plot.png
    set xdata time
    set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
    plot data u 1:2 with linespoints
```

What did I miss here https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#results in order to refer to RESULTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results block needs a name, which you supply *either* by naming the source block that generates it:

```
#+NAME: goodResult
#+begin_src bash 
echo "2057-01-01 10 
2057-01-02  7 
2057-01-03  3 
2057-01-04  2 "
#+end_src
```

***OR*** by adding a `#+NAME:` keyword as the first line of the `#+RESULTS:` block

```
#+NAME: resultName
#+RESULTS:
| 2057-01-01 | 15 |
| 2057-01-02 |  5 |
| 2057-01-03 |  3 |
| 2057-01-04 |  2 |
```

In the first case, references to `goodResult` will tell babel to compute the source block, and use the results in the current code block. In the second case, the named results block `resultName` will be used directly in the current code block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the Worg page you reference could perhaps be clearer about what it's telling you, which is that `results:` is an optional header argument for a `#+begin_src` block. This means that `results:` is *not* an in-buffer setting like `#+tblname`, which is how you are trying to use it here.

To be fair, the Worg page is all about `#+begin_src` blocks. Nevertheless, the examples for `results:` are not given in their full proper context. Perhaps they should be.